# Generate .env file for existing laravel app

Tags: laravel, git

I've been working on a Laravel app on a dev branch for a while. I just merged the dev branch into the master branch (via Tower, so switched to master branch and then merged dev branch into it) and pushed that to the remote.

The weird thing is that in my dev branch the `.env` file is now missing, while it was there before.

It should just be ignored as per the `.gitignore` file, but switching to the master branch shouldn't remove it, right?

Even more weird is that without the `.env` file my app is still working. I have ran the following commands:

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

and still my app is working without the `.env` file. Am I missing something here? Can I regenerate an `.env` file from existing config settings?

Comment: Btw. I don't think you should commit you're env file https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-commit-my-env-file

Comment: A checkout should not remove ignored files.

Comment: I am not committing my .env file. It's ignored as defined by the gitignore file, so that's working as expected. My question is why it disappeared and how I can regenerate it.

Comment: Env files are usually written, not generated. At least in my experience.

Comment: if your app is still working without `.env` youre likely not using the variables inside it. Double check if the file is not hidden. Switching branches should not remove files that are untracked.

Comment: OK so switching branches shouldn't delete the env file, that's clear now, thanks. I've changed values in the env file multiple times and these changes were always picked up by the app so that leads me to think the env file is indeed used. Through `cmd+shift+>` on my Mac and `ls- a` in terminal I don't see the env file...

Comment: Just restarted the dev server (`php artisan serve`), now it's not working anymore... I'll re-add the .env file.

Answer (score 1):

Some considerations:

- It is not recommended that you add the `.env` file to your remote repository. See more https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-commit-my-env-file
- make checkout to branch `master` will not cause your `.gitignore` files to be ignored
- It is better to have a .env.example file more securely than it is in .env (except password and security information). then you can just make `cp .env.example .env`. This file can be find on https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example